# Symfony3 report generation (html) of PHPUnit does not work

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, xdebug

I want to generate a report with PHPUnit: `sudo phpunit --coverage-html ./phpunit-report src/` but I get the following error: `Error:         No code coverage driver is available`. After some research on web I found that I've to enable the PHP extension xdebug and I do so in the file /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini on line:  `zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so"` After doing it so, I realize that the extension is enable as I can see it on symfony toolbar: [image]

But when I try to see the xdebug extension using CLI :`php -m | grep xdebug` I get null. Same thing with `php -i | grep xdebug`. Then at that point I really don't know whether the extension has not been enabled properly or ... any help please. Notice that when I load phpinfo() I also see the xdebug extension like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate Xdebug for the CLI SAPI. That binary uses a separate PHP configuration file (`php.ini`), not the one used by the webserver.

Comment: First of all thank you for this software (PHPUnit)  !! now after some research to find the right php.ini as I'm using Ubuntu + xampp I found and edit another one : /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini  but steel it does not work

Comment: I really don't understand what has happen but I just edit the same file /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini by adding the line zend_extension="/usr/lib/php5/20131226/xdebug.so" and it 's working now thunk you.